# Setting placeholder text jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, placeholder

I have this **working** code which I'm using to set placeholder values for username and password fields:

```
<script>document.getElementById("user_login").setAttribute("placeholder","Please enter your Email Address");</script>
```

and

```
<script>document.getElementById("user_pass").setAttribute("placeholder","Please enter your Password");</script>
```

Now I'm trying to apply this to a 3rd box which has the input ID `#memb_password_send-1-email-input` but this isn't a straight up element, it's an input field and using this ID (as above) obviously doesn't work.

Here is a picture of console:

[image: IMG 01]

**What would be the correct way to target this field with placeholder text?**

Comment: What do you mean with "straight up element"? I think that user_login and user_pass also are inputs?

Comment: please attach your code

Comment: @hallleron this is true they are input elements, by 'straight up elements' I mean things that can be styled/edited easily with no issues, I've tried several methods for the email input field but nothing seems to work

Comment: @VDesign Why can't you just add it to the HTML? Just add the attribute placeholder with the data...

Comment: @selten98 the form is outputted using a shortcode due to the membership setup on the site therefore I have no control over the HTML directly

Comment: What exactly happens when you do <script>document.getElementById("memb_password_send-1-email-input").setAttribute("placeholder","Lorem ipsum ...");</script>? The only important thing is that the input field has to be loaded before this script is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same method used to provide placeholder for username and password fields would work in this case as well as those are input fields as well. Just make sure that when you are writing this code in in-line script, do this after that input box has rendered i.e. after it's markup so that element is available to get selected.

Comment: Thank you! It was the placement of the code, it was after the element already but in the same row, I've moved it to the very bottom of the page and it's working now! :)